# How to wait for system() completion before advancing into next cycle

Tags: c, fork

I'm using `system("./foo 1 2 3")` within C to call an external application. I use it inside a for cycle and I want to wait for the foo execution to complete (each execution takes 20/30 seconds) before going into the next cycle iteration. This is a MUST.

The returned `system()` value only tells me if the process was successfully started or not. So how can I do this?

I looked into `fork()` and `wait()` already but didn't manage to do what I want.

Edit:Here's my `fork` and `wait` code:

```
for(i=0;i<64;i++){
        if((pid=fork()==-1)){
            perror("fork error");
            return -1;
        }
        else if(pid==0){
            status=system("./foo 1 2 3"); //THESE 1 2 3 PARAMETERS CHANGE WITHIN EACH ITERATION
        }
        else{                           /* start of parent process     */
            printf("Parent process started.n");
            if ((pid = wait(&status)) == -1)/* Wait for child process.      */
               printf("wait error");
            else {                       /* Check status.                */
               if (WIFSIGNALED(status) != 0)
                  printf("Child process ended because of signal %d.n",
                          WTERMSIG(status));
               else if (WIFEXITED(status) != 0)
                  printf("Child process ended normally; status = %d.n",
                          WEXITSTATUS(status));
               else
                  printf("Child process did not end normally.n");
            }
        }
 }
```

What happens when I do this is that the PC gets extremely slow to the point I need to manually reboot. So What I guess this is doing is starting 64 simultaneous child processes, causing the computer to become really slow.

Comment: Could you share your fork+wait code, and explain what did you try, what failed. `fork + exec + wait` would be the normal way of doing this.

Comment: Yes i know, I'm on the process of putting it here. Nice suggestion @domen

Comment: @JoãoPereira Why are you using `fork`?

Comment: I just tried with fork.. Initially I was using only `system`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was.

I saw here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file

that in order to save the stderr to file I needed to do `&>output.txt`.
So I was doing `"./foo 1 2 3 &>output.txt"` but that `&` causes the system process to go into background.

+1 to @Random832 for guessing it (even though I never said I was using `&>` -sorry guys, my bad ).

Btw, if you want the stderr to be exported to a file you can use `2>output.txt`

Comment: I don't know why they gave `&>` - the more typical way to do this is `>&`. But for full compatibility and to get both stderr and stdout in the same file you need `> output.txt 2>&1` - to get them in different files use `> output.txt 2> error.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

On a POSIX system, the `system` function should already be waiting for the command to finish.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html

> If command is not a null pointer, system() shall return the termination status of the command language interpreter in the format specified by waitpid(). The termination status shall be as defined for the sh utility; otherwise, the termination status is unspecified. If some error prevents the command language interpreter from executing after the child process is created, the return value from system() shall be as if the command language interpreter had terminated using exit(127) or _exit(127). If a child process cannot be created, or if the termination status for the command language interpreter cannot be obtained, system() shall return -1 and set errno to indicate the error.

The one thing to watch out for is if you're starting the program in the background within the command (i.e. if you're doing `"./foo &"`) - the obvious answer is just don't do that.

Comment: Please be careful with `system` and `popen` as those go through shell, and if any part is user controllable, commands could be easily injected.

Comment: It doesn't wait. I Debug the c code and the code jumps to the next line immediately after doing `status=system("./foo 1 2 3")` with status=0

Comment: @JoãoPereira Are you sure that the ./foo command is actually executing correctly and taking as much time as you expect it to? If you run it from the command line with identical parameters, does it sit there for 30 seconds before giving you a new shell prompt?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happens. The ./foo response is given as `stderr` though. Don't understand why but that's what's happening. And yes it is executing correctly, as I see the outputs (2 images) a while after in the designated folder

Answer (score 2):

After you call `fork`, the child calls `system` which starts another child that `foo` runs in.  Once it completes, the child continues the next iteration of the `for` loop.  So after the first loop iteration you have 2 processes, then 4 after the next, and so forth.  You're spawning off processes at an exponential rate which causes the system to grind to a halt.

There are a few ways to address this:

- After the call to `system`, you have to call `exit` so the forked off child quits.
- Use `exec` instead of `system`. This will start `foo` in the same process as the child.  A successful call to `exec` does not return, however if it fails you still want to print an error and call `exit` after `exec`.
- Don't bother with `fork` or `wait` at all and just call `system` in a loop, since `system` doesn't return until the command is completed.

EDIT:

This loop is exhibiting some strange behavior.  Here is the culprit:

```
if((pid=fork()==-1)){
```

You've got some misplaces parenthesis here.  The innermost expression is `pid=fork()==-1`.  Because `==` has higher precedence than `=`, it first evaluates `fork()==-1`.  If `fork` was successful, this evaluates to false, i.e. 0.  So then it evaluates `pid=0`.  So after this conditional, both the parent and the child have `pid==0`.

After applying one of the above changes, put the parenthesis in the right place:

```
if((pid=fork())==-1){
```

And everything should work fine.

Comment: About the 3 choices:
1-I'm going to try that;
2-After the 1st I'll try this one
3-I tried only with `system` and couldn't get the wanted result as the 64 processes were all starting concurrently and I want each one to start only after the previous one finishes..

Comment: What kind of exit are we talking about?If I do  `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);` after the `status=system("./foo 1 2 3")` the function exits after the first iteration is done

Comment: @JoãoPereira You probably want to `exit(status)` to reflect the exit status of `foo`.  The  child process that called `system` will exit, however the parent should continue with the next iteration.

Comment: @JoãoPereira Is this the actual code you're running?  Because the issues you're describing don't seem to match up.

Comment: Yes, with the exception of "./foo 1 2 3" of course. I'm going to try the `exit(status)` you suggested

Answer (score 0):

[wait(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html)

> All of these system calls are used to wait for **state changes** in a
>          child of the calling process, and obtain information about the child
>          whose state has changed.  **A state change is considered to be: the
>          child terminated; the child was stopped by a signal; or the child was
>          resumed by a signal.**  In the case of a terminated child, performing a
>          wait allows the system to release the resources associated with the
>          child; if a wait is not performed, then the terminated child remains
>          in a "zombie" state (see NOTES below).
>
> I**f a child has already changed state, then these calls return
>          immediately.  Otherwise, they block until either a child changes
>          state or a signal handler interrupts the call** (assuming that system
>          calls are not automatically restarted using the SA_RESTART flag of
>          sigaction(2)).  In the remainder of this page, a child whose state
>          has changed and which has not yet been waited upon by one of these
>          system calls is termed waitable.